Meteor scattering with RTL-SDR RTL2832U
What type of antenna and frequency is best for meteor scattering?
I have a RTL-SDR RTL2832U DVB-T tuner dongle and would like to learn how to use it.

never done meteoscatter myself! But I doubt it's the first thing you should do: by their very nature, these signals are very weak, and you'd need long observation time, or very low-noise receivers. Now, an RTL-SDR is not very low noise! Should still in principle be something you can do. I just don't know whether "I can see no signal, but that might be OK, there's no guarantee there is signal" is a good starting point for learning to use anything :)

Meteor scatter is really a form of passive radar, which is actually a fairly hot topic of research these days. Search for "passive radar" to get some ideas of the techniques being used.

@MarcusMüller Well, I have worked meteor scatter on 2 meter SSB. I had a 13 dbd antenna array, and used ordinary amateur radio equipment. And also having an RTL-SDR Blog v3, I can confidently say it could have replaced that equipment. :-)

@MikeWaters nice! So, medium-gain antenna; did you use TV stations as primary source of energy, or what?

@MarcusMüller Other amateur stations. I was in northwest Ohio USA and I worked stations out west. Utah is one, IIRC. Oh yes, I did use a 250 amplifier. Can't say what others had.
